# Allow root of current folder with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My `example.com/subdir/.htaccess` is:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
<Files "index.php">
Allow from all
</Files>
<Files "test.php">
Allow from all
</Files>
```

It works: `example.com/subdir/index.php` and `example.com/subdir/test.php` are available and not the other files, as desired.

Problem: `example.com/subdir/` or `example.com/subdir` aren't available (403 Forbidden), whereas it should display `example.com/subdir/index.php` as usual.

**Question: how to allow `/` (more precisely: `example.com/subdir/`) in this `.htaccess`?**

PS: I think this could be done without any RewriteRule because usually `/` is automatically mapped to either index.html or index.php.

Comment: PLease consider using the `FilesMatch` directive. It allows for the use of a regular expression to match files instead of just a name. Best _always_ is to start reading the documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#filesmatch

Comment: Thanks @arkascha for your comment. I have already read this documentation, but here the problem is not that I need regex (in this case I would use `FilesMatch` indeed), but that I don't know how to allow `/`.

Comment: Ah, OK, I failed to understand that from your question. Thanks for pointing that out. If I recall correctly then a `<FilesMatch "">` works?

Comment: @arkascha doesn't this match everything? i.e. every string contains the pattern `""`

Comment: I understood that it matches an empty file name. Because it is _not_ a regular expression. I would suggest that you simply try what happens...

Comment: @arkascha I just tried; when adding `<FilesMatch "">`, it matches *everything*, including `/test.log`, which I don't want.